# and operator ( && ) not working in Angular

Tags: angular, primeng

I have button that open dialog with blockui feature.I want to close dialog and set blockui boolean variable to false for not blocking ui.But in my html code `(click)="blockedDialog=false && displayAddDialog=false"` here just works first one so (blockedDialog=false) 2nd one(displayAddDialog=false) not working.How can i do that without going to method call.I mean can't we do this with && operator in html?

My html Dialog code :

```
<p-button [label]="'ekle' | translate" icon="pi pi-plus" (click)="showAddDialog()"></p-button>
<p-blockUI [blocked]="blockedDialog"></p-blockUI>
<p-dialog header="Godfather I" [(visible)]="displayAddDialog" [style]="{width: '50vw'}" [baseZIndex]="10000">
        The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, oversees his daughter's wedding. His beloved son Michael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's business. Through Michael's life the
        nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just like the head of the family, kind and benevolent to those who give respect, but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands against the good of the family.

    <p-footer>
        <button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-check" (click)="blockedDialog=false && displayAddDialog=false" label="Yes"></button>
        <button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-times" (click)="blockedDialog=false && displayAddDialog=false" label="No" class="ui-button-secondary"></button>
    </p-footer>
</p-dialog>
```

My Ts :

```
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  displayAddDialog: boolean;
  blockedDialog: boolean = false;
ngOnInit(): void {
this.displayAddDialog = false;
}

showAddDialog() {
    this.displayAddDialog = true;
    this.blockedDialog = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`blockedDialog = false` will resolve to `false`, so it will short circuit and terminate. If you want it to continue, you should use `||`:

```
blockedDialog = false || displayAddDialog = false
```

Another, better way, is to just separate the statements with `;`:

```
blockedDialog = false; displayAddDialog = false;
```

Best and most semantic way would be to create a `hideAddDialog` method, as you also have a `showAddDialog`

Comment: Thank you. Also i decreased statement to 1. I am just looking for displayAddDialog variable besides two of them . It did as expected

Answer (score 0):

Because the first expression returns false and the second expression is not evaluated after that. Therefore the second expression is never set.

Use a method call instead, and set these two variables in that method.

yeah otherwise use `;` to separate the two expressions as Poul Kruijit has put in the other answer.

**The alternative approach**

```
(click)="hideDialog()"
```

in the component ts file

```
hideDialog(){
  this.blockedDialog = false;
  this.displayAddDialog = false;
}
```